# SVG line cross animation for icons

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have two [icons](https://jsfiddle.net/jxie/ga61c3zs/1/), one in original state, one in crossed off state.
I want to animate the cross line but changing `dash-offset` is not useful since those are two different svgs.

I'm looking at [these](https://icons8.com/c/animated-icons) animated icons but still couldn't figure out the magic part. I want to ask:

- what should be the transition work flow?
- I prefer to use pure CSS, is it possible?

A working example would be appreciated.

Comment: If the only change is the line, why use two icons? You could just animate a path on the first icon?

Comment: because if you look closely, the 'off' icon has totally different svg paths, and there is a 'gap' between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animated icons on that page are quite complicated (more that they need to be IMO).  But basically what they are doing is sliding a rectangular mask in from right to left, that covers the first icon, and uncovers the second icon.

Here is a simplified version, using pure CSS, that hopefully makes it clearer.

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* slides the two masks to the left on hover */
svg:hover #bottom-rect,
svg:hover #top-rect
{
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform: translate(-24px, 0px);
}

/* slides the two masks back to the right when not hovered */
svg #bottom-rect,
svg #top-rect {
  transition: transform 500ms;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <defs>
        <mask id="bottom">
          <rect id="bottom-rect" width="24" height="24" fill="white" stroke="none"/>
        </mask>
        <mask id="top">
          <rect id="top-rect" x="24" width="24" height="24" fill="white" stroke="none"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>    
   
    <g mask="url(#bottom)">
      <path d="M12 1a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v8a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V4a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"></path>
      <path d="M19 10v2a7 7 0 0 1-14 0v-2"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#top)">
      <line x1="1" y1="1" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
      <path d="M9 9v3a3 3 0 0 0 5.12 2.12M15 9.34V4a3 3 0 0 0-5.94-.6"></path>
      <path d="M17 16.95A7 7 0 0 1 5 12v-2m14 0v2a7 7 0 0 1-.11 1.23"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with CSS.

You just show/hide the icons you want on hover. To animate the line, use CSS animations with `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`. Comments in code.

```css
/* for demo */
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} 

/* hide the off icon */
svg .off {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* when user hovers SVG, the on icon is hidden... */
svg:hover .on {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* ... and the off icon is shown */
svg:hover .off {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* initial values for the stroke
   -- these can be obtained with JS, 
   -- or you can work them out manually for CSS
*/

svg .line {
  stroke-dashoffset: 40px;
  stroke-dasharray: 40px;
}

/* when user hovers SVG, animate the line */
svg:hover .line {
  animation: addLine 800ms forwards;
}

/* values for line animation */
@keyframes addLine {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 40px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"> 
    <g class="on">
      <path d="M12 1a3 3 0 0 0-3 3v8a3 3 0 0 0 6 0V4a3 3 0 0 0-3-3z"></path>
      <path d="M19 10v2a7 7 0 0 1-14 0v-2"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
    <g class="off">
      <line class="line" x1="1" y1="1" x2="23" y2="23"></line>
      <path d="M9 9v3a3 3 0 0 0 5.12 2.12M15 9.34V4a3 3 0 0 0-5.94-.6"></path>
      <path d="M17 16.95A7 7 0 0 1 5 12v-2m14 0v2a7 7 0 0 1-.11 1.23"></path>
      <line x1="12" y1="19" x2="12" y2="23"></line>
      <line x1="8" y1="23" x2="16" y2="23"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but as you can see in the example website, their animation is way more smooth when the line crossing.